# Can the CAML Query in A View be modified to use the Username or UserId of the currently logged in user?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, caml-query

On a MOSS 2007 Team Site, I used the Web UI to add a View, and used the Web UI to filter it in order to fetch the items where Title equals ACME\Joe.

<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text">Acme\Joe</Value></Eq></Where></Query>

I opened this View in Designer and pasted some of the CAML that was generated above.

Is there a way to modify the XML so that the fixed "ACME\Joe" is replaced by the username or userid of the currently logged in user, whatever is easier to get? I can ensure the username, userid, or anything, for that matter, populates the Title field.

My goal is to have a view that returns the items created by the currently logged in user.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use [Me] keyword. Please check following article for further reference:

http://vspug.com/mirjam/2009/07/16/creating-a-custom-view-that-filters-on-the-current-user-or-me/